# Ruby: How to read maybe gzipped data from file or STDIN?

Tags: ruby, gzip, stdin

I would like to read data from an input file or STDIN - the input data may be gzipped.

For files this can be done with Zlib::GzipReader like this:

```
require 'zlib'

ios = File.open(file, mode='r')

begin
  ios = Zlib::GzipReader.new(ios)
rescue
  ios.rewind
end

ios.each_line { |line| puts line }
```

However, I fail to get the detection of zipped data from STDIN right:

```
require 'zlib'

if STDIN.tty?
  # do nothing
else
  ios = STDIN

  begin
    ios = Zlib::GzipReader.new(ios)
  rescue
    ios.rewind
  end
end

ios.each_line { |line| puts line }
```

The above works with gzipped data in STDIN, but regular data results in this:

```
./test.rb:14:in `rewind': Illegal seek - <STDIN> (Errno::ESPIPE)
        from ./test.rb:14:in `rescue in <main>'
        from ./test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

So, if I cannot rewind STDIN, how do I test if data in STDIN is zipped or not?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: Thank you :o). I discovered how nifty this forum is from biostars.org.

Answer (score 1):

Load data from STDIN into temporary file and only then parse it

```
require 'tempfile'

tf = Tempfile.new('tmp')

while $stdin.gets do
   tf.puts $_
end

tf.rewind
```

Comment: I am working with quite a lot of data here and would like to avoid the temporary file solution. It strikes me that GzipReader must read in a chunk of data in a buffer and unzip that if possible - or raise an error. GzipReader ought to have some method to test if the buffer contains zipped data - or return the buffer as an IO object.